# Selenium IDE - Command to wait for 5 seconds

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I´m using the Selenium IDE for Firefox and searching for a wait command.
My problem is that I want to test a website with a embedded external map.
This external map needs 3-5 seconds to load.

My commands:

```
open /Page/mysite.html
//Wait Command? (5 seconds)
ClickAndWait link=do something
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Use the [pause](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#pause) command and enter the number of milliseconds in the Target field.

Set speed to fastest (Actions --> Fastest), otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Thank you! I insered the command, but Selenium doesn´t pause. Command = pause, Value = 10000

Comment: Use `Target` instead of `Value`. Command = Pause, Target = 1000.

Comment: @Khairul glad you added that comment, it's been driving me mad as to why `pause()` won't work!

Comment: Speed has no bearing on the pause command, it is as @Khairul says instead: Put it in the target.

Comment: when you pause at the end of a test case when running a test suite it won't work

Answer (score 93):

**This will delay things for 5 seconds:**

Command: pause
Target: 5000
Value:

**This will delay things for 3 seconds:**

Command: pause
Target: 3000
Value:

**Documentation:**

http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#pause

[image]
[image]

Comment: So, set 5000 for 5 seconds

Comment: That's insane that they would make the target the value to wait in milliseconds. Love it. Thank you for posting this as I did not even try to enter the value in the target.

Answer (score 6):

For those working with `ant`, I use this to indicate a pause of 5 seconds:

```
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>5000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

That is, `target: 5000` and `value` empty. As the reference indicates:

> pause(waitTime)
>
> Arguments:
>
> - waitTime - the amount of time to sleep (in milliseconds)
>
> Wait for the specified amount of time (in milliseconds)

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is probably `waitForCondition` and writing a javascript function that returns true when the map is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! But is there now OOTB way to wait x seconds?

Comment: No, there's no direct way to just wait for x seconds.  See the [complete list of supported commands](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html).

Comment: pause  x000 seconds will wait for x seconds

Answer (score 2):

In case when you use Chrome exctantion you can set timeout in 'Target'. It helps for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you are looking for in C# (WebDriver/Selenium 2.0)

```
var browser = new FirefoxDriver();
var overallTimeout = Timespan.FromSeconds(10);
var sleepCycle = TimeSpan.FromMiliseconds(50);
var wait = new WebDriverWait(new SystemClock(), browser, overallTimeout, sleepCycle);
var hasTimedOut = wait.Until(_ => /* here goes code that looks for the map */);
```

And **never** use Thread.Sleep because it makes your tests unreliable

Comment: Much better option in Selenium 2.

Answer (score 0):

The pause command can be used directly in the ide in the html format.

If using java or C you could use Thread.sleep(5000). Time is in milliseconds. Other languages support "sleep 5" or time.sleep(5). you have multiple options for just waiting for a set time.

Comment: Thread.Sleep is never a good idea and that's why Selenium provides wait primitives. If you use them you can specify much higher timeout value which makes tests more reliable without slowing them down as the condition can be evaluated as often as it's required, eg. every 50ms.

Comment: My response in the thread.sleep is only related to answer the question for how to make it wait in the ide. As pause gets translated into thread.sleep when you convert from html to java or c in the ide.

Answer (score 0):

Before the command `clickAndWait` add the following code so the script will wait until the specific link to be visible:

```
   <tr>
        <td>waitForVisible</td>
        <td>link=do something</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
```

The practice of using the wait commands instead of pause is most of the times more efficient and more stable.

Answer (score 0):

This will wait until your link has appeared, and then you can click it.

`Command: waitForElementPresent
Target: link=do something
Value:`

Answer (score 0):

One that I've found works for the site I test is this one:

waitForCondition | selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().$.active==0 | 20000

Klendathu

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, For "Selenium IDE", I was also struggling that it doesn't pause. It will pause, if you give as below:

- Command: pause
- Target: blank
- Value: 10000

This will pause for 10 seconds.

Comment: Target should be 10000 and value should be blank

Comment: Not sure which browser's plugin you are trying but that worked fine for me in Chrome. Also depends which extension you are using.