# run test every 1 hour using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium

i have a web application. I have created a test using Selenuim IDE. I can execute the test manually which run perfectly.

I requirement is that this test should run automatically every 1 hour. There should not be any human interaction for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium IDE - Command to wait for 5 seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694981/selenium-ide-command-to-wait-for-5-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Use either [Windows Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) under Windows or [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) under Linux, these utilities can schedule program execution to the certain time or period.

Comment: how do i use windows task scheduler to have the selenium IDE execute automatically?